# Why does my RMI server exit before a client can connect?

Tags: java, rmi

After starting the program to run on the specified port, the program terminates before a client is able to connect to it.

```
    try {
        StudentService obj = new StudentService();
        Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4200);
        r.bind("localhost", obj);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the is the method that is located in the StudentService class that has been overridden.

```
int multiply(int s, int b) throws RemoteException {
    return s * b;
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

Comment: No 'connection' is being 'lost' here. There is no such thing as a connection in RMI. Your JVM is *exiting.*

Comment: NB This is the second wildly incorrect title in two posts from you. You need to be much more precise about what is really happening.

Comment: @EJP Ok. I will

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the documentation,

> UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject exports the supplied remote object to receive incoming remote method invocations on an anonymous TCP port and returns the stub for the remote object to pass to clients

So, there is no surprise your program ended without listening for incoming connections. This should work.

```
try {
    StudentService obj = new StudentService();
    UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

    Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4200);
    r.bind("localhost", obj);

} catch (RemoteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this solved the problem that I was having. Thank you

Comment: Consider up voting the questions and answers in stack overflow that you found helpful so that it will be helpful for others. Thanks :)

Comment: @KMuir The export step is only required if `StudentService` does not extend `UnicastRemoteObject`, a fact which is impossible to determine from your question.

Comment: I fail to see how the quoted documentation extract explains anything about this question, or how the code segment answers it, or what problem in the OP's code it addresses.